# Extract text info from popup page using python

Tags: python, web-crawler

Is it possible to extract the text information from a popup page automatically using python?
I have google play store app link :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana
If you scroll down to the "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION" section, you will find "Permissions". By clicking 'View details" underneath will popup a page. Are those text information in the popup extractable?
And how do I get the information from the main page source if it is doable?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do the following:

1) Set up a webdriver to control the website.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

2) Right click "view details" and select inspect source. This will open the source code of the page. The highlighted portion corresponds to that button. You can right click and copy the xpath and use this to call a click function.

3) Once the new page opens, navigate your driver to this page and follow the same instructions as in step 2 to select the text you want. You can then use the innerhtml function to grab the text from this element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not familiar with the webdriver. I was trying different options. So far the best I can get is the permission data without the category header. Need to study webdriver a bit to see if it can help out.

Comment: Finally I got the webdriver to work. Got what I wanted. Thanks again for the direction.

Comment: That's awesome! And now you've got some handy code for later. If you wouldn't mind, could you select my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be rather complicated: you'll have to dig through the HTML to find out what the button does (the link is actually a `button` element). The best would be to use a Google Play Store API, which doesn't exist as of right now. The easiest option would therefore be to go through a third-party API which would crawl the play store for you. Here's an [example](https://apptweak.io/api).

I won't walk you through the whole process, but you'll probably have to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use curl to pull the data. The permission data is available in the JSON output. New challenge is to get the category list matching up with the data. Still struggling.